# Subtracting fixed effect term for visualization

Tags: fixed-effects-model

Suppose that I run a fixed effect model

$$y_{ij}=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{ij}+d_i+\epsilon_{ij}$$

where $d_i$ is the fixed effect model for group $i$.

Now that I want to show the data, is it appropriate for me to show all $(x_{ij},y_{ij}-d_i)$ points so that all of them lie near one single line? Thanks a lot!